# how can I exclude in a thread messages from the trash before they are permanently deleted in 30 days?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-imap

a filter puts certain emails in a label
then I read them with

```
var folder = "[Gmail]/MAJTableauLR";
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(folder).getThreads();
```

and extract data
the thread is then trashed.

```
for (n in threads) {
        var message = threads[n].getMessages();
        message[0].moveToTrash();
    }
```

During a subsequent execution of the same script, it includes the messages put in the trash whereas if I put them in the trash it is good to exclude them from this folder. So how can I exclude these messages from the trash before they are permanently deleted in 30 days??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

###### Deleting it permanently

Instead of moving to the trash, delete them permanently. Do you need to enable the [Gmail API V1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail):

```js
function main(){
  const threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Custom').getThreads()
  for(const th of threads){
    th.getMessages().forEach(msg=>deletePermanently(msg.getId()))
  }
}

function deletePermanently(msgId){
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', msgId)
}
```

###### Check the message/thread is already in the trash

You have the method for both [`GmailMessage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) and [`GmailThread`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) for check if it is already trashed: [`isInTrash()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#isintrash)

```js
function main() {
  const threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Custom').getThreads()
  for (const th of threads) {
    //Will jump to the next no in trash
    if (th.isInTrash()) continue
    for (const msg of th.getMessages()) {
      // Same for msgs
      if (msg.isInTrash()) continue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you i try this
I understood that in a thread if a message is sent to the trash and not another, the trash message is persisted for the thread

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain with an example what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was saying that using movetotrash in a thread, if all messages from it are sent to the trash, the thread is no longer straddling the trash and the label folder. so trash messages are no longer persisted in the label's thread.
and with the Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', msgId) function that I just tried, it's even more radical, since the message is completely deleted hahaha. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it! Remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.